# Traversing a DOM tree to get (name,value) pairs of attributes and leaf nodes

Tags: java, dom

I want to traverse through an XML file in DOM for the purpose of retrieving as (name,value) pairs all:

1. Attribute names and values;
2. All leaf node names and their text content;

So given the following XML file as an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<title text="title1">
    <comment id="comment1">
        <data> abcd </data>
        <data> efgh </data>
    </comment>
    <comment id="comment2">
        <data> ijkl </data>
        <data> mnop </data>
        <data> qrst </data>
    </comment>
</title>
```

What I want as name value pairs are:

```
text=title1
id=comment1
data=abcd
data=efgh
id=commment2
data=ijkl
data=mnop
data=qrst
```

Comment: I'm glad! You might want to use Java DOM API. http://java.sun.com/developer/codesamples/xml.html#dom

Comment: Why not trying XMLBean, and I just saw you asked about XPath in the recent questions you asked? Name value pair without context cannot express your data in xml.

Comment: @Clark That’s true, but I don’t just want to get the (name,value) pairs, but rather do a traversal in this manner, and any time I encounter these pairs, I will do some more processing...

Comment: You want some query in XML by attributes? You can try XQuery/XPath

Answer (score 4):

An easier solution might be to use XPath to extract all name value pairs as in the following example. You could also skip the DOM construction and call evaluate directly on the `InputSource`. The XPath expression

```
//@* | //*[not(*)]
```

matches the union of all attributes and all nodes that don't have any child nodes.

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class Test {

    private static final String xml = "<title text='title1'>\n"
            + "  <comment id='comment1'>\n"
            + "    <data> abcd </data>\n"
            + "    <data> efgh </data>\n"
            + "  </comment>\n"
            + "  <comment id='comment2'>\n"
            + "    <data> ijkl </data>\n"
            + "    <data> mnop </data>\n"
            + "    <data> qrst </data>\n"
            + "  </comment>\n"
            + "</title>\n";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));

        XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xp = xpf.newXPath();
        NodeList nodes = (NodeList)xp.evaluate("//@* | //*[not(*)]", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        System.out.println(nodes.getLength());

        for (int i=0, len=nodes.getLength(); i<len; i++) {
            Node item = nodes.item(i);
            System.out.println(item.getNodeName() + " : " + item.getTextContent());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about something like:

```
    String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
        "<title text=\"title1\">\n" +
        "    <comment id=\"comment1\">\n" +
        "        <data> abcd </data>\n" +
        "        <data> efgh </data>\n" +
        "    </comment>\n" +
        "    <comment id=\"comment2\">\n" +
        "        <data> ijkl </data>\n" +
        "        <data> mnop </data>\n" +
        "        <data> qrst </data>\n" +
        "    </comment>\n" +
        "</title>\n";

    try {
        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));

        DocumentTraversal traversal = (DocumentTraversal) doc;

        NodeIterator iterator = traversal.createNodeIterator(
          doc.getDocumentElement(), NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, null, true);

        for (Node n = iterator.nextNode(); n != null; n = iterator.nextNode()) {
            //System.out.println("Element: " + ((Element) n).getTagName());
            String tagname = ((Element) n).getTagName();
            if(tagname.equals("title")) {
                System.out.println("text=" + ((Element)n).getAttribute("text"));
            }
            else if(tagname.equals("comment")) {
                System.out.println("id=" + ((Element)n).getAttribute("id"));
            }
            else if(tagname.equals("data")) {
                System.out.println("data=" + ((Element)n).getTextContent());
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Unhandled element");
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Okay, so you weren't happy with that, how about this:

```
 String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
        "<title text=\"title1\">\n" +
        "    <comment id=\"comment1\">\n" +
        "        <data> abcd </data>\n" +
        "        <data> efgh </data>\n" +
        "    </comment>\n" +
        "    <comment id=\"comment2\">\n" +
        "        <data> ijkl </data>\n" +
        "        <data> mnop </data>\n" +
        "        <data> qrst </data>\n" +
        "    </comment>\n" +
        "</title>\n";

    try {
        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));

        DocumentTraversal traversal = (DocumentTraversal) doc;

        NodeIterator iterator = traversal.createNodeIterator(
          doc.getDocumentElement(), NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, null, true);

        for (Node n = iterator.nextNode(); n != null; n = iterator.nextNode()) {
            //System.out.println("Element: " + ((Element) n).getTagName());
            String tagname = ((Element) n).getTagName();

            NamedNodeMap map = ((Element)n).getAttributes();
            if(map.getLength() > 0) {

                for(int i=0; i<map.getLength(); i++) {
                    Node node = map.item(i);
                    System.out.println(node.getNodeName() + "=" + node.getNodeValue());
                }
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(tagname + "=" + ((Element)n).getTextContent());
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: thanks, but I actually needed a generic solution. I.e. given any arbitrary XML file, it transverses over all attribute (name,value) pairs, and all leaf nodes (name,text-content) pairs...

Comment: You can't do that, as some of your data is stored in attributes, some in the text content. You either standise your xml to always store what you want in the same place, or you do what I've shown.

Comment: Can’t you have an algorithm that for each node, it extracts all attribute name-value pairs, and then recurses for each child node, until we have a lead node, in which we extract the node name and text content...

Comment: I've added a second demo based on Larrys suggestion. However if you have more than one attribute you are going to get more than one output pair.