# Put XML element node and text node to the array of string

Tags: java, xml

Please help me to put element and text nodes into an array of `String`s.

For example an .xml file has:

```
<soap:Envelope>
  <soap:Body>
    <ser:getTitle>
      <!--Optional:-->
      <ser:title>Meeting</ser:title>
    </ser:getTitle>
    <ser:getDiscription>
      <!--Optional:-->
      <ser:discription>this is the meeting</ser:discription>
    </ser:getDiscription>
    ...
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelop>
```

Now I want to place the values into the `String[] key, value` as follows:

```
key[0] = "title";
value[0] = "meeting";
key[1] = "discription";
value[1] = "this is the meeting";
```

... and so on.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need them in 2 `String[]`? Why not `Map<String, String>`?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. If you want to extract certain values, than see my answer below. If you want to parse the XML and bring it to a flat represenation of key, value pairs than you would need to iterate over the DOM tree (see link below). But that could cause problems in hierachical/nested XML structures, etc. Keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DOM](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-xml/dom.html) to parse your input XML and use something like:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import java.io.File;

public dumpXMLTags(...) {
  String[] keys; // you would need that with appropriate size initialized
  String[] values;  

  // Parse your XML file and construct DOM tree
  File fXmlFile = new File(PATH_TO_YOUR_XML_FILE);
  DocumentBuilder dBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
  Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
  doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

  // Traverse DOM tree (make sure is not empty first, etc)
  NodeIterator iterator = traversal.createNodeIterator(
      doc.getDocumentElement(), NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, null, true);

  int i = 0;  // index to you key/value Array

  for (Node n = iterator.nextNode(); n != null; n = iterator.nextNode()) {
     keys[i] = ((Element) n).getTagName();
     values[i] = ((Element)n).getNodeValue();
     i++;
  }
}
```

Alternatively you could use XPATH with the

```
//@* | //*[not(*)]
```

expression, as described here: [Question 7199897](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199897/traversing-a-dom-tree-to-get-name-value-pairs-of-attributes-and-leaf-nodes)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));

    XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xp = xpf.newXPath();
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList)xp.evaluate("//@* | //*[not(*)]", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

    System.out.println(nodes.getLength());

    for (int i=0, len=nodes.getLength(); i<len; i++) {
        Node item = nodes.item(i);
        System.out.println(item.getNodeName() + " : " + item.getTextContent());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think he wants to read/parse the xml and put the key-value pair in some other collection.

Comment: Ah I see, the question was edited while I was writing my answer. Than he still can use a DOM parser to retrieve the fields and feed them into a map or whatever collection is suitable.

Comment: Dear, thanks for the prompt response but I want to input these values (element node and corresponding text node)  one by one to other program.  I need help because in future I would not know  which xml file it would be or what is the tag name. I want that any xml file be an input and output would be every element node + text node one by one.

Comment: So if I get you right, you want to dump each tag without regard of the  underlying structure? Only those of a certain tag-name or simply all?

Comment: dear, yes all the tags +value one byone  untill xml file ends.

Comment: Thanks dear I will check it and get back to you if I find any difficulty. Many thanks.